# code to check if array is in ascending is showing errors

Tags: java

I am creating code to check if an array is in ascending order. I have created code that seems logical to me; however, when I input an array that *is* in ascending order, I receive an error message (but when I input an array that is *not* in ascending order, the code outputs "false, as it should). Here is my code:

```
public class Ordered {
  public static boolean isSorted(int[] numbers) {
    int length = numbers.length;  
    for (int i=0; i <= length-1; i++) {
      if (numbers[i] > numbers[i+1]) { //here is where I think the error message is showing the issue is
        return false;
      }  
    }
    return true;     
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. It's a good idea to post the errors when you get the errors. Also: consider what happens when you're at `length - 1`, recalling that Java arrays are 0-indexed.

Comment: When you get to the last index of the array, you're checking i+1 which is probably giving you an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException at the `if (numbers[i] > numbers[i + 1])` condition.

Loop until, `i < length - 1` and not until `i <= length - 1`

```
public static boolean isSorted(int[] numbers) {
    int length = numbers.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < length - 1; i++) {
        if (numbers[i] > numbers[i + 1]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That seemed to solve my issue. However, I am confused as to why it should not be i<= length -1.

Comment: Let's say if the length is 6. When i is 5,  i<= length -1 evaluates to true. In the next, if statement when you access numbers[i + 1], Java throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException because you are accessing index 6, but for an array of length indexes are allowed from 0 to 5.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, so you don't go beyond the last index of the array:

```
public static boolean isSorted(int[] numbers) {
    int length = numbers.length;  
    for (int i=0; i < length-1; i++) {
        if (numbers[i] > numbers[i+1]) { 
            return false;
        }  
    }
    return true;     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

THis will work because numbers[i + 1] should always be last element of the array if all prev are in ascending orders.

public static boolean isSorted(int[] numbers) {

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length - 2; i++) {
    if (numbers[i] > numbers[i + 1]) {
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

}